# External plugins architecture for React+ Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I’ve more than 2 years experience in React and Redux, the last times I got the interesting task  which I can’t completed well. The task assume we have the application(SaaS) with many kind of modules which provided some service for the customers and the customers is big corporations with IT departments whose can write own modules with React-route, redux store etc. and integrade with our platform. So I need to build the mechanism which provide the some type of API which integrate the customer external module/plugin with our redux store. Our application using Ducks folder structure for an approach. I understand webpack build the application and give the production ready compiled version, but can’t imagine how external modules can be integrated on runtime. So I opened this question for discussing the best ways to get the more qualified solution, I know it’s sounds weird for some of you guys but maybe these discussions may help us to find the lighter :)

Comment: You can absolutely have server-side rendering and deliver only components that are needed at runtime.  https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+react+rendering+node and for ASP.NET Core https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+react+rendering+asp.net+core

Comment: thank you for response, but is it impossible for front-end implementation?